# Separating out pandas series for pyplot

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I currently have a set of series in pandas and each series is composed of two data sets. I need to separate out the two data sets into lists while retaining the series information, ie. the time and intensity data for 58V.

My current code looks like:

```
import numpy as numpy
import pandas as pd 

xl = pd.ExcelFile("TEST_ATD.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
series = xl.parse("Sheet1")

voltages = []

for item in df:
    if "V" in item:
        voltages.append(item)

data_list = []

for value in voltages:
    print(df[value])
```

How do I select a particular data set from the series to extract them into a list? If I ask it to `print(df[value])` returns my data sets, an example of which looks like:

```
Name: 58V, dtype: int64
 0.000     0
 0.180     1
 0.360     1.2
 0.540     1.5
 0.720     1.2
          ..
 35.277    0
 35.457    0
 35.637    0
NaN        0
```

Ultimately I plan to plot these data sets into a line graph with pyplot.

~~~ UPDATE ~~~

using

```
for value in voltages:
    intensity=[]
    for row in series[value].tolist():
        intensity.append(row)
    time=range(0,len(intensity))
    pc_intensity = []
    for item in intensity:
        pc_intensity.append((100/max(intensity)*item))
    plt.plot(time, pc_intensity)
    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_ylim([0,100])
    plt.title(value)
    plt.ylabel('Intensity')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.savefig(value +'.png')
    plt.clf()
    print(value)
```

I am able to get the plots of the first 8 data series (using arbitrary x axis), however, anything past the 8th series and my plots are empty? I have experimented and found this to be due to some of the series being different lengths. I'm confused as to why this would effect the plots as the x-axis is directly related to the length of the data set it is being plotted against?

Comment: Series has no columns.  Are you talking about a frame?

Comment: Oh I assumed they were indexed columns? Is there a way for me to extract the data from a series frame then?

Comment: @Charlietrypsin when I answer these questions, I usually experiment with the data and attempt to produce what the asker is asking for.  In your case, I have no data to look at and I have no idea what you are looking for.  This is why we ask people to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I can see there are a few elements of what you trying to do that you don't understand very well.  That's ok, read the link I provided and try to ask your question in way that makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Okay I have come back to this will a clearer head and have edited the question. Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to acheive but I'll take a guess

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 10), 'B': range(1, 10), 'C': range(1, 10), 'D': range(1, 10), 'E': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4]})
for col in df.columns:
    print(df[col].values.tolist())
```

this would print every columns of your dataframe as list

if you are just trying to plot something why not just use

```
df.plot()
```

Comment: Using `pd.DataFrame` doesn't work unfortunately. I will experiment with `df.plot()`

Comment: `import pandas as pd`    or juste use `pandas.DataFrame`   this has nothing to do with the answer I am juste creating a dataframe so you can replicate my answer since you did not provide a reproductable example

Comment: I have already imported pandas as `pd`, the problem is with extracting the data from the series. Using a `.plot()` with a specific dataframe also just creates a blank plot.